# How to use regular expression result into another expression

Tags: shell, command-line, command-substitution

I have two regular expressions i.e. command1 and command2 where i need to combine both expressions into a single expression using `|` for that command1 output should be passed to next expression.

### command1:

```
grep 0x017a /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/device | cut -d/ -f6
>> Output : 00:00:01
```

### command 2:

```
head -n1 /sys/bus/pci/devices/00:00:01/resource | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tail -c 9
```

How to use command1 output (00:00:01) into command2 and combine into a single expression?

Comment: Does `head -n1 /sys/bus/pci/devices/\`grep 0x017a /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/device | cut -d/ -f6\`/resource | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tail -c 9` work?

Comment: I have tried but didn't work this way.

Comment: what does command 2 return, what is the desired output?

Comment: "head -n1 /sys/bus/pci/devices/00:00:01/resource | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tail -c 9 "
 output is : da00000.

Comment: Here, 00:00:01 is command 1  output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the output of one command as argument of the second command the mechanism of *command substitution* `$()` can be utilized. For example:

Instead of

```
$ whoami
jimmij

$ ls /home/jimmij/tmp
file1 file2
```

you can do

```
$ ls /home/"$(whoami)"/tmp
file file2
```

---

In your specific case the single command become

```
head -n1 "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$(grep 0x017a /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/device | cut -d/ -f6)/resource" | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tail -c 9
```

Notice I also quoted the entire expression, [read here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80886) why you should do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$(command)` syntax (or the older `` `command` `` syntax).

```bsh
DEVICE=$(grep 0x017a /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/device | cut -d/ -f6)
head -n1 "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$DEVICE/resource" | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tail -c 9
```

Oh.  "Combine into a single expression" similarly.

```bsh
DEVICE=$(grep 0x017a /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/device | cut -d/ -f6)
OUTPUT=$(head -n1 "/sys/bus/pci/devices/$DEVICE/resource" | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | tail -c 9)

echo "Output is $OUTPUT"
```

Comment: May i know how can we combine both line into single line ?

Comment: Get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS varnames: one day you'll use `PATH=...` and then wonder why your script is broken.